# Custom Timer Job is not appearing in the JobDefinitions Page in CA

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-timer-job

I am trying to implement a custom timer job in my `SP 2013 on-premises` appln.
I have created the same. But the timer job is not appearing in the timer job definitions page.

I have activated  and deactivated the feature multiple times, and after doing multiple `IISRESET` and `sptimer services` restarts, and `sp admin service` restarts , the timer job failed to  visible.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint; 

  namespace RILTILPTimerJob.RILTTimerJob
     {
  public  class FreezeDocTimerJob  :SPJobDefinition
   {
    HashSet<string> seenUids = new HashSet<string>(); 

    public const string JobName = "FreezeDocument Timer Job"; 
    public FreezeDocTimerJob() : base() { }
    public FreezeDocTimerJob(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer 
    server,SPJobLockType targetType) : 
      base(jobName, service, server, targetType)
        {   }

      public FreezeDocTimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp, 
       string strUrl) : 
      base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.ContentDatabase)
        {
            this.Title = "FreezeDocument Timer Job";
        }

  /// <summary>
  /// execute method of rilt timer job
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="ContentDatabaseID"></param>
       public override void Execute(Guid ContentDatabaseID) 
       {  
           try   
           {
               SPWebApplication webApp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
               SPList objlistRILTList = webApp.Sites
         [0].RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList("RILTLIST");
               SPListItem objRILTTaskItem = objlistRILTList.Items.Add();
               objRILTTaskItem["Title"] = "New_Task_RILTWFTIMER_" + 
      DateTime.Now.ToString();
               objRILTTaskItem.Update();
            }   
           catch (Exception expinXecute_RILTTimerJob)  
           {    
             }  
         }   
        }  
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go through your Feature Event Receiver code again that is creating a custom timer job on "FeatureActivated" event. Before writing code for creating a timer job, delete the timer job if it is already existing and then create the custom timer job.

Also assign the title of timer job inside below method:

```
public FreezeDocTimerJob(string jobName, SPService service, SPServer 
    server,SPJobLockType targetType) : 
      base(jobName, service, server, targetType)
        {  
            this.Title = "FreezeDocument Timer Job";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. You have to specify that the scope of the Feature should be "Site" in visual studio for SharePoint 2013 that is how timer job creating.

[image]

Comment: I think , scope of the timer job must be WEB APPLICATION. and NOT site collection. am working in SP 2013 ON-PREM. can you pls elaborate why SiteCollection will work

Comment: not sure I have got same issue and referred some post previously and found this solution and it works well for me.